# How to insert data in associate mdoe in sequelize.js , node

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Many to many association between role and permission. Association done successfully

Joining table name is `RolePermission`

I save data in role like this

```
models.Role.create(role)
  .then(function(data){
  // here I create RolePermission with role.id and req.body.permission_id
```

})

I want to know either I manually insert data in RolePermission or any `sequelize` or node.js method available?

Like I see `parent.createChild` . How I use it or best practice?

Comment: You can use data.setPermission(permissionInstance or array of permissionInstance)

Comment: can you elaborate this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

When I had this same problem, I found that the documentation is not very clear. So let me give you an example of my own, maybe it helps you out.

```
//Oportunity hasMany client
//client hasMany oportunity
//join model is ClientOportunity
Oportunity.belongsToMany(Client, {
  through: ClientOportunity, 
  foreignKey: 'oportunity_id', 
  as: 'client'
});

//create oportunity and add clients
//data is an array with the oportunity fields plus
//an attribute named 'clients' which is an array of clients
//[{id: 1}, {id: 2}] like so
Oportunity.create(data).then(function(created) {
  //you have to make a Sequelize instance out of this clients
  var clients = data.clients.map(Client.build.bind(Client));

  //created is a Sequelize instance of the created Oportunity
  //so we use the magic function defined by sequelize to add clients
  //if you are trying to add a client that was already related to the oportunity, sequelize is smart enough to avoid repeating it.
  //note that if you are updating the clients, you have to pass all the clients all the time. Otherwise you are overwriting.
  created.setClient(clients).then(function(result) {});

});
```

Hope you can use this as an example to solve your problem

Comment: created.setClient is not a function

Comment: setClient is a magic function sequelize creates, in my case it has that name because I have a relation with the model Client. You will have accordingly with your models